# How to use swagger pet example?

Tags: rest, swagger, insomnia

I try to use this swagger http://petstore.swagger.io/#/ with API Rest client like Insomnia or Postman.
The problem i must to set an "API key" to use API but where ?

In Insomnia i can set this authorization settings but which use ?
[image]

Answer (score 0):

API key is optional in the Petstore demo, you can call most (all?) endpoints without the API key.

If you want to use the API key, add the following header to your requests:

```
api_key: special-key
```

But from what I can tell, the response is the same with and without the API key.